# jQuery version clashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have sort of run into an issue.. I am possibly using way too much jquery on my site now, and all the scripts require their own version of jquery at the moment.. so they're pretty much clashing and with them all included into one page, nothing works.

Is anyone able to give me some advice on how to get around this?

So far I am using:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.js

http://pastebin.com/kWZHNiiu

I've tried removing just one or two, and they all fall into a loop of some working, and others not. The main issue seems to be really coming from the version 1.2.3 > http://pastebin.com/kWZHNiiu

Thank you
- James

Comment: Simple answer.  Reduce your page to **one** version of jQuery.  Either get rid of the plug-ins that aren't compatible with your main version of jQuery or port/fix them yourself to be compatible with it.  Multiple versions of jQuery is generally just a pain.  It can be done with lots of care and careful isolation into closures, but it's really not the desired way to go.

Comment: version 1.2.3 of jquery is about 5 years old - there is no reason why you should be using it.

Comment: check this out http://interface88.blogspot.in/2012/07/using-multiple-version-of-jquery-on.html

Comment: can I just add, the 1.2.3 version was only used as it came with a script that I bought, and so when ever I try using another version it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Look into http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict

Although I would suggest to use only one version for your site.